# Linux Tool to read values of the stack

Tags: c, linux, security

I would like to know if there is a Linux tool that allows you to read the values of the program stack?? For instance when running the binary of a program containing the line:

```
foo(parameter);
```

the parameter would be put on the stack, and I would like to know if there is a tool to access it.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged this as `security`, you'll probably want to read "Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit":

http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

Comment: great link, this was exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 5):

Gdb?

There are also some backtrace functions in glibc.
http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it sounds like you just want to run a debugger.  If you compile your program with the -g option then you can use gdb like:

gdb myprogram

Now set a break point at your function and you can view the values of the variables in the current scope.

If you are a C beginner it is very much worth your time to learn gdb (Gnu debugger).

Comment: You don't need to have compiled a binary with -g.  Obviously more debugging info helps, but you'll be able to see the extern (i.e. shared-linker-visible) functions on the call stack, and read the numeric values of their arguments.  It's optimization that gets in the way of debugger use (especially -fomit-stack-pointer on gcc!), not really the lack of -g.